# Squareup API, how to correctly handle Credit Card errors and show to user

Tags: php, square-connect

**This question is specifically for *Square* e-commerce api.**

Hopefully this question can reach an Square's dev team.

I am building the embedded payment form for my website and I am not sure how to handle the credit card related errors. 
specifically speaking.

when credit card charge end point thrown an exception. It returns something like this

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [category] => PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR [code] => VERIFY_AVS_FAILURE [detail] => Postal code check failed. ) )
```

What I want to do is to look at the error and determine if the error is a result of something outside of customers' control.

For example if the error is an API error, then I just want to show an generic message to tell user to try again later. whereas if the error was because user typed their postal code incorrectly. I want to tell user specifically to correct their postal codes.

so I found this link
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/?q=error#type-errorcode

it shows me a list of error category. it also shows a list of specific error codes.

**But So my question is,** 
which category or which list of codes are a result of end user error?

right now I have a switch case statement, if any of the following shows up in the `[code]` field I will show related error to user and anything else will just show generic error.

**Is this the right way of doing it?**

```
CARD_EXPIRED    
INVALID_EXPIRATION  
INVALID_EXPIRATION_YEAR 
INVALID_EXPIRATION_DATE 
UNSUPPORTED_CARD_BRAND  
INVALID_CARD
CARD_DECLINED   
VERIFY_CVV_FAILURE  
VERIFY_AVS_FAILURE  
CARD_DECLINED_CALL_ISSUER
```

Comment: Please read [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/243450) before attempting to ask more questions that are opinion based that invite argumentative discussion because they do not have a single agreed upon answer.

Answer (score 3):

I show the user whatever error string or strings are in the response. There may be more than one error. Here's my PHP code:

```
    try {
      $result = $transaction_api->charge($access_token, $location_id, $request_body);

    } catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
      $response = $e->getResponseBody();
      $error_string = "";
      foreach($response->errors as &$error) {
          $error_string .= $error->detail . "<br>";
      }
      // Return to the credit card form, passing $error_string as a $_POST value
      // so it can be displayed. I did that by putting a <form> here containing
      // $error_string and anything else that needs to be passed back as
      // "hidden" POST data followed by javascript to submit the form.
      exit(); // since the credit card was rejected.
    }
    // if you get here, there were no errors; go ahead and record the approved payment.
```

Comment: Uh...don't do this. The majority of possible errors should NOT be shown to the user as they pertain to either errors in your implementation or the square api itself.

Answer (score 1):

Its up to you to decide which errors to show to your users. In general developers probably just pass the error message through, or show a generic error for all errors.

How you have set it up seems fine, though when I think about `user error` I just think about mistyping something, not having an expired credit card.